# Unable to download my iOS app to my iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to download my ios app to my iPhone and run it from there.
Also I have registered with Apple iOS developer program.
My Xcode version is 6.2 (6C131e).
iOS version on my phone is iOS 8.4.1

So I connected the iphone 5s to my computer using the USB. I can see Xcode recognized my device. Clicking on the run button displays this message
"The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted."
iPhone many be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode."

Can someone help me as what could be the issue?
Thanks
Borna

Comment: did you download the certificates already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all try to update XCode to the newest version.
2. Make sure you have downloaded the proper certificates.

Comment: Thank you all. After upgrade to the latest Xcode, I was able to download the app to my iphone

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to download XCode 6.4

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html

```
Xcode 6.4 includes the iOS 8.4 SDK to support development for iOS 8.4 apps.
```